# IMD measurements and power levels of inputs

Tags: intermodulation-products

If I do a two tone test and increase the power of only one tone by 1db, will the 3rd order harmonic be up by 3db only for the one I increased or for both or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your distortion is cubic (which is the usual but not always correct assumption made about systems on which we do two tone IMD tests), then the distortion output will increase by the order of that frequency in the IMD frequency expression.

If you have two tones f1 and f2, and increase f1 amplitude by 1dB, then

3f1 increases by 3dB
2f1 +/- f2 increases by 2 dB
f1 +/- 2f2 increases by 1 dB
3f2 remains unchanged

This leads to the rather intuitive behaviour that raising one input tone also raises the 3rd order IMD tone on that side.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of [IMD measurements](https://dl.cdn-anritsu.com/en-us/test-measurement/files/Application-Notes/Application-Note/11410-00816C.pdf)

[image]

An here mathematical background ...

[image]

Just use the definition about rms voltage if necessary.

Also note that "distortion" can change

1- Quiet Point of amplifier ... from \$a0\$ to \$a0 + a2/2*(A^2+B^2) \$

2- Change "gain" of amplifier ... (global coefficient of cos(f1) or cos(f2))

Was for **f1** : \$a1*A\$ then became \$(3/4*A^3*a3 + 3/2*A*B^2*a3 + A*a1)\$

Was for **f2** : \$a1*B\$ then became \$(3/2*A^2*B*a3 + 3/4*B^3*a3 + B*a1)\$

which can be different.